# Defined methods in base class increases all inherit classes size independently of the method use

Tags: c++, inheritance

If I declared a method in the base class but the inherit classes don't use it, the binary size increase? And if only some inherit classes use this method, all inherit classes increase their size?

Comment: size of classes and size of binary are orthogonal.

Comment: (non virtual) methods doesn't increase sizeof of the class.

Comment: The class is a red herring. If you declare a function and don't use it, does the size increase?